# Passing parameter in Jenkinsfile to a shell command within a Docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, groovy, parameters, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile with a String parameter `env_vars`. With this parameter I want to set custom environment variables which I want to set later with a shell command within the started Docker container. It is important to set such environment variables on runtime.

This is my simple `Jenkinsfile`:

```
pipeline {
    options {
        timestamps()
    }
    agent {
        node {
            label 'master'
        }
    }
    parameters {
        string(name: 'env_vars', defaultValue: 'MY_USER_PASSWORD=abc MY_USER_NAME=def', description: 'the ENV variables to set before starting the tests')
    }
    stages {
      stage ('TESTS') {
        steps {
            script {
              withDockerRegistry([credentialsId: 'XXX', url: 'http://example.com']) {
                  withDockerContainer(image: 'myDockerImage:latest') {
                      withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'cred1', variable: 'cred1'), string(credentialsId: 'cred2', variable: 'cred2')]) {
                          sh '''
                            # here we go to run npm
                            ${env_vars} npm run test -- chrome --tag=enabled
                            '''
                          }
                      }
                  }
            }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

And this error I will get in Jenkins:

`/var/lib/jenkins/jenkins3/jobs/zTestMG/workspace@tmp/durable-40340d0e/script.sh: line 4: MY_USER_PASSWORD=abc: command not found`

One possible workaround is using `eval` for the shell command:

`eval "${env_vars} npm run test -- chrome --tag=enabled"`

But I don't want to use eval, because later I have to evaluate the result of the `npm run` command. And when using `eval` I will get new problems.

How can I solve the problem to use the String parameter in the shell command within the Docker container?

Comment: Why don't you set them when starting the container ? Otherwise you can use docker exec to execute 'export' like commands to export your environment variables before starting jenkins.

Comment: I want to pass multiple ENV variables with the parameter. I've updated my example code. Before runtime I don't know the ENV variables. So, it's not possible to set the variables while starting the container, because the ENV variables vary in quantity and value. And how to integrate a `docker exec` in my given `Jenkinsfile`?

Comment: docker exec -i YOUR_CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash -c "export VAR1=VAL1 && export VAR2=VAL2 && npm run test -- chrome --tag=enabled" would probably run npm with the desired envvars, on an already running container. The envvars values/quantity can be scripted when calling docker exec.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a possible solution for me. I replace my shell command in two different once:

```
export ${env_vars}
npm run ${run_script_method} -- ${browser} --tag=${tags}
```